# Script message not displayed in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a strange problem (for me who am not familiar with Asp.net).
I have these lines of code in a button:

```
     System.Text.StringBuilder oString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
     oString.AppendLine("alert('WAIT MESSAGE!');");
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ModalPopup", oString.ToString(), true);
     Validation();
```

I would expect, when I press the button, to see the waiting message appear and, after the click, the validation starts.

Instead what happens is that the validation is started FIRST and the message is displayed AFTER!
Why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems you are trying to run client and server code together, so it can be quite complex in terms of working in order. What does `Validation` function do?

Comment: Nothing in particular, it analyzes data from a text file.

Comment: I suggest you that try `OnClientClick` in button like : `<asp:Button  Text="Click!" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('WAIT MESSAGE!');" />` instead of using RegisterClientScriptBlock in this case. I can help you if you provide more info about your button.

Comment: Selim Yıldız, thanks, this is the best way.

Comment: I have added an answer, please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944815/5519709).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [`OnClientClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick) attribute of button instead of  `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in this case.

`<asp:Button Text="Click!" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('WAIT MESSAGE!');" />`

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick):

> Use the OnClientClick property to specify additional client-side
>   script that executes when a Button control's Click event is raised.
>   The script that you specify for this property is rendered in the
>   Button control's OnClick attribute in addition to the control's
>   predefined client-side script.

So that when you click the button, first alert will be shown then server code will start running as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably running it asynchronusly. Take a look on the concept [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
It could be better if you add the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock part